# Why doesn't ArrayList.contains(Object.class) work for finding instances types?

Tags: java, arraylist

Say I have an ArrayList which is populated with objects of different types...

```
ArrayList<Fruit> shelf = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
Apple apple = new Apple();
Orange orange = new Orange();
Pear pear = new Pear();

shelf.add(apple);
shelf.add(orange);
shelf.add(pear);
```

I want to find out if `shelf` contains an `Orange` object. I've tried

```
shelf.contains(Orange.class)
```

but this doesn't return true. My understanding is that `contains` makes use of the `equals` method for object comparison, so I'm not sure why this is the case.

I realise I can simply iterate through the ArrayList and check the type of the objects individually, but I'm curious as to why `contains` doesn't behave the way I expect it to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are correct, `contains` uses `equals`.  However, an instance of a class is not equal to an object of the class, i.e. `Orange.class.equals(new Orange())` is false.

You will need a custom method to check for a list containing an instance of a class.

```
public static <E> boolean containsInstance(List<E> list, Class<? extends E> clazz) {
    for (E e : list) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(e)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's a Java 8 version making use of the Stream API and lambdas:

```
public static <E> boolean containsInstance(List<E> list, Class<? extends E> clazz) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(e -> clazz.isInstance(e));
}
```

Comment: This is how I've currently implemented the check, but I thought using `contains` may have let me eliminate the loop. I misunderstood the difference between a class instance and the actual object. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean containsObjectOfType(Object o){
 for (int i=0;i<shelf.getSize();i++){
  if (shelf.get(i).getClass().equals(o.getClass())){
   return true;
  }
 }
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

methods like Contains , uses the equals method to compare two object,
you must Override the equals method that inherited from Object class to every newly created class.
Override it according to the fields of your own class.
it should compare all of fields of an object.
also it must check if the object is null and check that argument is an instancOf .
this link can help more :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

From the Javadoc for [ArrayList#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

You need to provide the `contains` method with an instance of the class, not the class object.

```
ArrayList<Fruit> shelf = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
Apple apple = new Apple();
Orange orange = new Orange();
Pear pear = new Pear();

shelf.add(apple);
shelf.add(orange);
shelf.add(pear);

shelf.contains(apple); // returns true
```

Comment: This will check if the specific instance of the class is in the list, not if any objects of the type in Question are in the list.